# C++ text to multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, multidimensional-array, fstream

So I need to make a program that sums numbers from this text file:

> 3
>
> 22 5126717910121751622546
>
> 29 88888888888888888888888888888
>
> 40 2525255125133485451578436833138834387837

The first line shows the number of rows, and the following lines are the numbers that I need to sum. The first number in one of following lines shows number of digits of the second number.

Output file should be like this:

> 2525255125222374345594043632149474899271

I figured out that I have to use multidimensional arrays. I'm new to C++ and not used to multidimensional arrays so I need some help. Thanks in advance!
P.S. sorry if my English was bad.

Comment: On SO you need to ask a specific question, it's not okay to state a problem and expect us to tell you how to do it or write a solution.  Please read e.g. [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: Please post the code you already have, and the part you are stuck on (along with error messages, where applicable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since those integers are quite big, you need to store them in string and define operator + for those strings (actually big integers)

You can do the following to store them in 1D vector since the "number of digits" is not relevant if you really do BigInteger add. Meanwhile, you only output the sum not the number of digits in result.

```
   vector<string> data;
   ifstream dataFile("dataInput.txt");   //or you can use stringstream
   long numbers = 0; 
   dataFile >> numbers;
   long digits = 0;
   string currentNum;   
   while (dataFile >> digits >> currentNum)
   {
     data.push_back(currentNum);
   }
   //now add those integers
```

Add for BigInteger is straightforward.